# Python POST Request with an Image

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I'm trying to request to my flask webserver with an image using python and just can't get it to work.

Using cURL it's simple:

```
curl -XPOST -F "file=@image.jpg" http://127.0.0.1:5001
```

But in python using my code:

```
import requests

with open("image.jpg", "rb") as a_file:
  file_dict = {"image.jpg": a_file}
  response = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5001", files=file_dict)
  print(response.text)
  print(response.status_code)
```

I simply get the HTML of the site returned and status 200. Not the JSON that returns using cURL (and is what I want returned).

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use follow code

```
files = {'file': open('image.jpg', 'rb')}
 
r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5001', files=files)
print(r.text)
```